# LITERAL_STARTS_FROM_LETTER in PyCharm for Django's manage.py

Tags: django, macos, python-3.x, pycharm, macos-sierra

While in PyCharm, if I run `Tools` > `Run manage.py Tasks...` I get the normal manage.py@{System} environment that can correctly run tasks, such as `runserver`, `makemigrations`, etc. Though, before I type the task to run (auto-complete correctly works as well), I am presented with a prompt that has a warning. My prompt `manage.py@{System} >` is followed by a red squiggly-underline with the popup warning of:

> LITERAL_STARTS_FROM_LETTER expected, unexpected end of file

Because everything still works it's not a pressing issue, but I believe resolving this would allow PyCharm to run as intended. I have not found anything online or from JetBrains support.

```
PyCharm Version:
PyCharm 2016.3.1
Build #PY-163.9735.8, built on December 14, 2016
Licensed to {Me}
Subscription is active until October 25, 2017
For educational use only.
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Comment: Jetbrains/YouTrack case:
"PY-17218 There is LITERAL_STARTS_FROM_LETTER inspection in Django and App Engine consoles"